# Attiny88 as SPI slave

Tags: arduino-uno, attiny, spi

I have programmed Attiny88 with Arduino IDE 1.6.5 using https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore . I chose Attiny88 because it's the cheapest Attiny (as low as $0.5) and at the same time has 28 pins with dedicated SPI.  I wrote a code for arduino to work as SPI master, and a code for Attiny88 as SPI slave but I get only 0 as answer from Attiny.

SPI master code for ARduino UNO

```
#include <SPI.h>

// set up the speed, data order and data mode
SPISettings settingsA(2000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0); 
const int slaveAPin = 10;

void setup() {
  // set the Slave Select Pins as outputs:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("SPI ON"); 
  pinMode (slaveAPin, OUTPUT);
  SPI.begin(); 
}

uint8_t stat, val1, result;

void loop() {
   // read two bytes from device A
   SPI.beginTransaction(settingsA);
   digitalWrite (slaveAPin, LOW);
   // reading only, so data sent does not matter
  stat = SPI.transfer(0);
  val1 = SPI.transfer(0);
  digitalWrite (slaveAPin, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  Serial.println("data");
  Serial.println(stat); 
  Serial.println(val1);
  Serial.println("end");    
  SPI.endTransaction();
  delay(300);
}
```

SPI slave code for Attiny88:

```
#include <SPI.h>

// set up the speed, data order and data mode
SPISettings settingsA(2000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0); 
const int slavePin = 14;
const int ledPin = 9;

uint8_t stat, val1, val2, result;

void setup() {
  // set the Slave Select Pins as outputs:
  pinMode (slavePin, INPUT);
  pinMode (ledPin, OUTPUT);
  // initialize SPI:
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  SPI.begin();
  stat =128;
  val1= 1;
}

void loop() {

  if (slavePin==LOW) {
    SPI.beginTransaction(settingsA);    
    SPI.transfer(stat);
    SPI.transfer(val1);
    result = SPI.transfer(0);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, result);
    SPI.endTransaction();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not appear to be configuring the slave as an SPI slave. Merely changing the pin modes won't achieve this. Example code at [SPI - Serial Peripheral Interface - for Arduino](http://www.gammon.com.au/spi) - however that does not specifically mention the Attiny88.

In my example in reply #1 on that page I have this code:

```
  // turn on SPI in slave mode
  SPCR |= bit (SPE);

  // have to send on master in, *slave out*
  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);
```

This sets SPCR bit MSTR to zero (by not mentioning it). If you call SPI.begin() it will be activated in **master** mode.

It looks like the Attiny88 has the same register.

So in my opinion your code merely has two SPI masters.

Also, you seem to be doing 3 transfers in the master, but only 2 transfers in the slave.